# laravel request file return null (enctype added)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

when i upload anything it returns null but if i try to return $_FILES in my controller it returns my uploaded files, i had added enctype="multipart/form-data" but still no luck

this is my form

```
<form action="{{url('add_attachments')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf @method('put')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label class="small">Tambahkan lampiran</label>
            <div class="form-group mb-1 upload">
                <input type="file" name="lampiran[]" multiple accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,application/pdf" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class ProposalController extends Controller
    {
        public function add_attachment(Request $request, $id)
        {
            return $request->file('lampiran'); //return null
            return $_FILES; //return {"lampiran":{"name":["7680cf333da548d4213fd5f574b66ffbdccba917.jpg"],"type":["image\/jpeg"],"tmp_name":["\/tmp\/phpBIcJYs"],"error":[0],"size":[138198]}}
        }
    }
```

Comment: it work, just not return `UploadedFile` object as string, you can try `dd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<input type="file" name="lampiran[]" multiple accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,application/pdf"/>` is an array **lampiran[]**

try this

```
public function add_attachment(Request $request,$id)
{
    return $request->file('lampiran.0');
}
```

or

```
public function add_attachment(Request $request,$id)
{
    foreach($request->file('lampiran') as $image){
         dd($image):
    }
}
```